# AngularJS Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider when using $filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

This question is not something new but the thing is I have been spending a couple of hours on searching and trying to figure out what is wrong with my code and I found nothing yet. Please give me some idea! Thanks in advance.

my text-upper-case.js (where I define my filter)

```
'use strict';

var UpperCase = (function() {
  /*@ngInject*/
  function UpperCase(input) {

    return function(input) {
      input = input.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1');

      return input[0].toUpperCase();
    }
  };

  return UpperCase;
})();

module.exports = UpperCase;
```

my filter module (module.js)

```
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');
var UpperCase = require('./text-upper-case');

angular
  .module('myApp.filters', [])
  .filter('UpperCase', UpperCase);
```

and this is my main app.js where I inject my app dependencies

```
'use strict';

var angular = require('angular');
require('./filters/module');

angular
  .module('myApp', ['myApp.filters']);
```

error message:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: inputProvider <- input <-
>   UpperCaseFilter
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=inputProvider%20%3C-%20input%20%3C-%20UpperCaseFilter
>       at framework.js:8573
>       at framework.js:12902
>       at Object.getService [as get] (framework.js:13055)
>       at framework.js:12907
>       at getService (framework.js:13055)
>       at injectionArgs (framework.js:13079)
>       at Object.invoke (framework.js:13101)
>       at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (framework.js:12948)
>       at Object.invoke (framework.js:13109)
>       at framework.js:12908(anonymous function) @ framework.js:21741(anonymous function) @
>   framework.js:18470Scope.$digest @ framework.js:25187(anonymous
>   function) @ framework.js:25364completeOutstandingRequest @
>   framework.js:14309(anonymous function) @ framework.js:14586

in the view:

```
<table>
 <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in h.room_information">
   <td>{{key | UpperCase}}</td>
     <td>{{value}}</td>
   </tr>
```

my project structure:
[image]

Comment: Error tells you which provider but you left that out

Comment: oh I forgot the error message. just a minute!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to inject anything into the function returned by the filter.

Change

```
var UpperCase = (function() {
  /*@ngInject*/
  function UpperCase(input) {
```

To

```
var UpperCase = (function() { 
  function UpperCase(input) {
```

Comment: I know but it's only for minifying purpose. I remove it and things are still the same

Comment: create a demo that reproduces this